# How to trade US-based derivatives such as options as a non-US person?

Tags: options, trading, international-trading

I lived in the UK for a while, but now I'm heading back to Romania. I tried signing up on Charles Schwab, Fidelity and a few others, but it looks like no broker accepts applications from Romanians living in their home country. I also tried, for the sake of it, to check if they accept Bulgarians, but once again I could not proceed with the application.

What should one do in this situation? Is there any way to buy option contracts if no broker allows you to sign up? Can you trade with the CME Group directly?

Comment: Fidelity and Schwab aren't geared toward traders.  Interactive Brokers offers trading in nearly 200 countries, including Romania.  I don't know what limitations, if any, that they place on traders in different countries.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. Is there anyone else you recommend, as a backup?

Comment: I would look for reputable brokers that offer  international trading and then contact them one by one to see if you can trade with them from Romania.

Comment: I had similar issues (UK Citizen). Interactive Brokers was the one I eventually found that would facilitate it.